# NodeJS `fs.readdir` not reading hidden files on macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, file

- NodeJS Version: v15.6.0
- macOS Version: v10.15.7

Given the following file hierarchy:

```
/root
  |- /dir1
  |    |- .another-hidden-file.txt
  |
  |- /dir2
  |    |- some-file.txt
  |
  |- .hidden-file.txt
  |- index.js
```

And the following code (index.js above):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const content = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
```

I would expect the following output:

```js
console.log(content);
    // -> ['dir1', 'dir2', '.hidden-file.txt', 'index.js']
```

However the following output is obtained:

```js
console.log(content);
    // -> ['dir2', 'index.js']
```

Sync, Async, and Promises versions all give the same result.

I've also tried a lower level approach with [fs.opendirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opendirsync_path_options) with same results.

As far as I know, hidden files should be accessible with `fs.readdir`. Instead, even directories containing these files seems to be ignored (`dir1` in the above example).

Comment: what does `ls -la@` say?

Comment: @georg it shows all files/directories as expected.

Comment: I see. Are user/group/permissions the same for visible and hidden files?

Comment: @georg same permissions for hidden/visible files under Finder's "Get Info".

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get `[ '.hidden-file.txt', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'index.js' ]` when I test that code (macOS 11.4, zsh 5.8, Node v14.16.0).

Comment: @Quentin thank you for your response. In fact, I tested it on a standalone directory and found that the issue was caused by Babel not copying dot files during build process. It was driving me crazy. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional testing, I found that the issue was caused by Babel not copying dot files during the build process (see Babel #5052).

I solved it by using `--include-dotfiles` flag.